# Does vitamin E in oil liquid form help to eliminate wrinkles on face?

Tags: dermatology, self-healing-repairing, wrinkles, vitamin-e

It is sometimes recommended by dermatologists for topical use to promote wrinkle smoothing.

---

Does vitamin E in liquid oil form help to fade wrinkles?

Answer (score 1):

Topical application of vitamin E may reduce the length and depth of facial lines and wrinkles, according to the [University of Maryland Medical Center](http://www.umm.edu/health/medical/reports/articles/skin-wrinkles-and-blemishes). One specific form of vitamin E that has this benefit is alpha-tocopherol cream. Using such a cream can also reduce skin roughness.

[Step-by-step guide about usage of vitamin E for skin](https://www.livestrong.com/article/329997-how-to-rub-vitamin-e-on-face-for-wrinkles/)

[Precaucious of usage](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/06/21/vitamin-e-oil-tips_n_3477654.html)

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Good start. You reference Uni of Maryland but do not provide a link  to it. Further improvement might be possible by increasing the quality of links by using more reputable sources. Inspiration for those might be found here: [quality of references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references).